# From which version, IE can support Object.create(null)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-create

You can create an object in JavaScript in many ways:

```
// creates an object which makes the Object, prototype of data.
var data1 = new Object(); 

// Object literal notation; Object still is the prototype of data2.
var data2 = {}; 

// anotherObject is now the prototype of data3.
var data3 = Object.create(anotherObject); 

/* data3 is an object which can be verified bye typeof operator, 
   however, it now has no prototype and you can 
   build everything from scratch. */
var data3 = Object.create(null);
```

But I don't know which versions of IE support the last method, i.e. `Object.create(null)` method?

Comment: And what about of using inline object initializer `{}` or Object constructor `new Object()`, and don't lose your time with IE-specific behaviors?

Comment: @Matias, I want to have an object with no prototype. You can't achieve that with `{}` or `new Object()`.

Comment: You can't have an object without prototype in JavaScript, because the archetype of an object in this scripting language causally is the propotype! :D JavaScript isn't OOP, it's "prototype-oriented".

Comment: @Matias, [turns out that you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), and that's exactly what I want. To have `null` as the prototype of my object, or in other words, to have no prototype at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check Wikipedia's [JavaScript version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history).  If you find 1.8.5 version - and this is the language version where you find this Object factory method available - 9th version of Internet Explorer is the one supporting that.

The [ECMAScript 5 Compatibility Table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) also has this information.

You can also try for yourself using one of Microsoft's IE virtual machines (available from [here](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) or, for very old versions of IE, [Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE).

Comment: thanks for the link. However, it doesn't talk about Object factory method, and I checked it in IE8. It worked. `Object.create(null);` works in IE8.

Comment: I don't know why it worked in yours IE8, it doesn't in mine. And I checked in MSDN. "Object.create Function (JavaScript)  is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 standards mode and Quirks mode."

Comment: @Andy I don't know really, because at the time I was answering OP I did some research and I gave him these links, but I didn't tried it in IE8 myself. Maybe you're right.

Comment: @Andy or maybe I checked it in IE8 myself... but actually I don't remember what I did a lot of months ago haha

Comment: ES5 Object.create is not supported in IE8, of course if you're trying it with a hacked browser or in emulated mode, you won't notice it: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.create