# Object.create on IE6+

Tags: javascript, object

I have a little problem, because I wrote my plugin using Object.create and it's working only on IE9+.

My plugin definition:

```
$.fn.MYPL = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        myplg = Object.create(MYPL);
        myplg.init(options, this);
    });
};
```

But before every JS code I have the following:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== "function") {
    Object.create = (function () {
        function F() {} // created only once
        return function (o) {
            F.prototype = o; // reused on each invocation
            return new F();
        };
    })();
}
```

It works fine on IE9+ but IE6 and IE7 (even IE8) seems to be not supporting Object.create or what? Am I missing sth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [From which version, IE can support Object.create(null)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023255/from-which-version-ie-can-support-object-createnull)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I'm looking for something equivalent to the Object.create since it's not supported in IE6+.

Comment: The `Object.create` patch in your question works just fine in IE6/7.

Answer (score 0):

Check Wikipedia's [JavaScript version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history).  If you find 1.8.5 version - and this is the language version where you find this Object factory method available - 9th version of Internet Explorer is the one supporting that.

The [ECMAScript 5 Compatibility Table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) also has this information.

You can also try for yourself using one of Microsoft's IE virtual machines (available from [here](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) or, for very old versions of IE, [Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE).

Sourced from [From which version, IE can support Object.create(null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023255/from-which-version-ie-can-support-object-createnull)

Answer (score 0):

Older IE versions will not support `Object.create`. Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Try to create object using constructor which is described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain